# Как поменять строки в файле на php?

Tags: php

Помогите написать программу. Смысл такой: есть файл file.txt, есть скрипт index.php
В файле самом текстовом есть строки вида:
*строка1

строка2

строка3*
Нужно сделать так, чтобы после запуска скрипта файл обновлялся, а там сами строки были такого вида:
*"Строка1"

"Строка2"

"Строка3"*

То есть в начале и конце строки вставлялись кавычки. А первое слово строки начиналось с большой буквы.

Answer (score 2):

```
$str = file_get_contents('file.txt');
$arr = explode(' ', $str);
foreach($arr as $k=>&$word){
   $word = '"' . ucfirst($word) . '"';
}
file_put_contents('file.txt', implode(' ', $arr));
```

Код на [`Ideone.com`](http://ideone.com/CUzffk)

Comment: хм...он меняет только одну строку...и ставить кавычки не по строкам а по всему тексту в файле

Comment: @skarui, ну, фундамент у вас есть, остальное сами, вы же программист.

Comment: $arr = explode(' ', $str); => $arr = explode("\n", $str);
\n - символ переноса строки

Comment: и `uc_first` -> пляски c `mb_strtoupper()` и первым символом.

Comment: Если строка из одного слова, то можно этим изменить первый символ:    
[http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mb-convert-case.php][1] 
[1]: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mb-convert-case.php